# Pull request with one file whilst other files pushed on master

Tags: git

I want to make a pull request from a different branch than master but when I do that it includes the files that I pushed in master and I want the PR to only be a specific file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to open a PR that includes many commits or only one (the last one)? Does you last commit (the one you want to open a PR for) includes only the desired file? what dos `git log -1 --name-only` show?

Comment: Pull requests aren't for *files*. They are for *commits*. This stuff is a bit complicated and not easily described well on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are other revisions with more changes besides the file you care about past the point where master is? You can do this:

```
git checkout -b a-new-branch the-base-branch # the base branch might be origin/master, set it accordingly
git checkout master -- the-file-i-care-about # you want to see the file the way it is in _your_ master, right?
# the file should look like the way you want
git commit -m "I only care about this file"
# feel free to push and create the PR
```